# Mobile Vision google API not working on android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services, google-vision

I am currently working on implementing an Android application that can detect String from a bitmap Image using the Google mobile vision API but when I am trying to test the application the TextRecognizer.isOperational() method is always false. I read somewhere that the API initially downloads a native package so initially it returns false. After few tries it is still false.

FYI: I also provided the proxy settings to the emulator so that there is no issue in downloading the native package.

So is it possible to test it over an emulator or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have google play services installed in emulator?

Comment: Yes and the emulator is also build with a google api

Comment: Have you tried using a real-device? The emulator has plenty of limitations. If it works on device and not on emulator, you've got your answer already.